# Relative/Absolute CFC path in Open BlueDragon

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfc, openbd

I'm trying to migrate an existing ColdFusion codebase from Adobe CF8 to OpenBD. My files include something like this:

```
/cfc/one.cfc
/cfc/two.cfc

/app/page.cfm
```

In CF8 I had a mapping from 'cfc' to '/cfc', and in page.cfm I had:

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="cfc.one" jsclassname="oneCfc">
<cfajaxproxy cfc="cfc.two" jsclassname="twoCfc">
```

and then in Javascript I could call the CFC using:

```
var c = new oneCfc();
```

...and life was good.

---

Under Open BD (v2.0.3b) however, I can't seem to call the CFC functions from Javascript. The proxy is declared as before, and I can create the object in Javascript, but when I try to call a function I get the following error in my browser dev tools:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/cfc/one.cfc 404 (Not Found)
```

It appears to be using a relative path in Javascript when it tries to call the function, even though it's already got the object created.

The CFC is valid according to OpenBD (I can browse to `./cfc/one.cfc?wsdl`, and I can call functions on it using `./cfc/one.cfc?method=getData` etc). It doesn't seem to matter whether I have a mapping defined in OpenBD or not.

The one workaround that seems to work is having the CFC in the same function as the calling CFM file, but this isn't a very good solution when I want to reuse the CFC code from many different pages.

Has anyone got CFCs in other directories working under OpenBD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference: this problem was resolved (more or less) in OpenBD 3.0, released early March 2013.

In 3.0 the code that creates the AJAX proxy .js file was [modified](http://websvn.openbd.org/websvn/diff.php?repname=OpenBD&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fnaryx%2Ftagfusion%2Fcfm%2Ftag%2Fcfajaxproxy%2FcfAJAXPROXY.java&rev=1971) to include the lines:

```
javascript.append( " this.remoteCFC = '" );
javascript.append( CFC.replace('.', '/') );
javascript.append( ".cfc';\r\n" );
```

While it still does not take into account any server-side mappings, it at least allows you to reference a path that is not a child of the current .cfm page:

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc=".cfc.one" jsclassname="cfcOne">
```

(note the leading `.`, which is replaced with a `/` by OpenBD. In previous versions of OpenBD this would generate an error)